# What is the "father's profession" (conditio it professio) listed here?

Tags: poland, prussia, latin

I've got the following archive scan from 1844 in Gułtowy baptism book. I'm trying to decipher the father's profession of child Margaretha born 4th of July to Valentius and Maryanna (line 19). I also can't decipher the note after godparents - I'm assuming it also lists their professions.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

"Conditio et professio" means "(social) status and profession". There are two such columns here, one for the parents and one for the godparents (patrinorum). Said status/profession for Valentius and Maryanna parents is "inquilini", which translates to "resident", but might carry a more specific meaning in this locale (for example, whether they did or did not own land). The status/profession of the godparents is "coloni", so "farmers" (again, this can indicate something more specific).

Answer (score 4):

Building on what @jadepx translated and this being from 1844 [Grand Duchy of Posen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duchy_of_Posen) (part of Kingdom of Prussia), about [30 years after abolition of serfdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abolition_of_serfdom_in_Poland): *inquilini* (plural) would be *komornik* / *komornicy* in Polish (a poor peasant living in another peasant's chamber (*komora*); but richer than an itinerant worker - word *komornik* has a completely different meaning now). *coloni* (plural) would be *zagrodnik*/*zagrodnicy*; peasants owning a small plot of land (*zagroda*), enough to sustain themselves, usually not enough to sell any produce.

- [Pre-abolition peasant classes in Poland](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie_ludno%C5%9Bci_wiejskiej_w_Polsce) (in Polish).
- [Dictionary of Latin occupations used in Polish genealogical documents](http://genepedia.pl/index.php?title=S%C5%82ownik_zawod%C3%B3w_%C5%82ac.-pol) (in Polish).

Answer (score -1):

I can see among the jobs:
coloni / cotoni - cotton picker?? referring to harvester

sastor - Tailor

Hortalana(o)- gardener

Inquilini / jnquilini -  Housekeeper, live-in servant, caretaker

The I was sometimes substituted by J.

Comment: Your father was housekeeper, live-in servant, caretaker

Comment: In case the complete lack of upvotes doesn't make it clear: this answer is 100% incorrect. Very creative, but completely false.

Comment: Ok, JPmiaou since my answer is an error, kindly give an explanation. Don't leave unfounded opinions.

Comment: _colonus_ "farmer" has absolutely nothing to do with cotton, nor does it mean anything remotely like "harvester" (except insofar as farmers hopefully do engage in that activity, occassionally).

Comment: The word for "tailor" is _sartor_. And I don't know what it has to do with the question you're answering. Likewise for _hortulanus_ "gardener".

Comment: _inquilinus_ (plural _inquilini_) has had many meanings over the centuries, but "housekeeper" is not among the ones I have ever seen for it. I believe that in the time and place in question, it meant a specific sort of relationship between an agricultural worker and the land he worked, roughly "cotter" in English terms. (And no, that word doesn't have anything to do with cotton, either.)